# Python is throwing error when reading from a JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, dictionary

I have some JSON file with the following contents :

```
{
  "name": "",
  "street": "",
  "street_number": 26,
  "district": "VILA MARESIA",
  "city": "Raposa",
  "state": "",
  "country": "BR",
  "latitude": ,
  "longitude": 
  }
```

Now loading this file is throwing the error as below:

```
    with open(r"C:\Users\dverma25\menus-folder\menus-folder-MA\rt.json",'r', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-8150dd6a3e1d> in <module>
      2         logger.info("Start processing the file {}".format(file))
      3 #         t = json_file.read()
----> 4         json_data = json.load(json_file)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297 
    298 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 9 column 15 (char 153)
```

I got the reason behind this is value for the field "latitude" is missing which neither an empty string nor None(Because the datatype in source API is double for this field). Can anyone suggest a way to open the file and load it in json maodule.

**PS** : I also tried by opening the file and used josn.dump(file_obj.read()) but this has the issue that it's also taking all the carriage returns inside the dump().

Comment: you dont have a json file as what you have posted isnt valid json.

Comment: I know it's not a valid json but the Application from where I am getting the data has been designed in this way. So really to find a way to work around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case you could load your invalid json string from the file then use a crude str.replace on the invalid entries setting them to null.

```py
import json

my_json = """{
  "name": "",
  "street": "",
  "street_number": 26,
  "district": "VILA MARESIA",
  "city": "Raposa",
  "state": "",
  "country": "BR",
  "latitude": ,
  "longitude": 
  }"""

my_json = my_json.replace(": ,", ": null,").replace(": \n", ": null\n")
print(json.loads(my_json))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'name': '', 'street': '', 'street_number': 26, 'district': 'VILA MARESIA', 'city': 'Raposa', 'state': '', 'country': 'BR', 'latitude': None, 'longitude': None}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but this is throwing an error for the case when the value for the anyone of the fields (latitude or longitude) is present because those are the numeric values, not a string. The error I'm getting : JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 12 column 3 (char 255).

Comment: What do you mean? based on your example data as a minimum reproducable example the above data and replace works and allows the json to be successfully parsed

Comment: It's my bad I forgot to erase extra comma(,). It's working fine thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your file isn't properly formatted JSON. Specifically these lines:

```
"latitude": ,
"longitude":
```

They look like key-value pairs of that dictionary without the value part. They should look like this:

```
"latitude": "",
"longitude": ""
```

Comment: I know it but I have already mentioned that in PS that source API has defined it as a type of double.

Answer (score 0):

some time you have ' instead " in the data file and you will get similar error as the one you got
for example

```
import json 
json_data = "{'key':'value'}"
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)
```

and to solve it just replace ' to " the data before you pass to the object

```
import json 
json_data = "{'key':'value'}"
json_data_clean = json_data.replace("'","\"")
json_obj = json.loads(json_data_clean)
```